# Concave down increasing example

Tags: calculus

I'm looking for a `concave down increasing`-function, see the image in the right lower corner.

Basically I need a function `f(x)` which will rise slower as x is increasing. The `x` will be in range of `[0.10 .. 10]`, so `f(2x) < 2*f(x)` is true. Also if

I would also like to have some constants which can change the way/speed the function is concaving.

Any suggestion on a formula?

[image: Concave up/down graphs]

Comment: $\log(x)$ is a common one

Comment: What about $\log_a (x)$ ?

Answer (score 5):

If you are restricted to a positive $x$, you could use

$$ f(x) = a \sqrt{x}, \quad a > 0 $$

which satisfies

$$ f(2 \cdot x) = a \sqrt{2 \cdot x} = \sqrt{2} \cdot a \sqrt{x} = \sqrt{2} \cdot f(x) < 2 \cdot f(x) $$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{equation}
f(x) = -\frac{a}{x^b}
\end{equation}
where $a$ is a positive number and $b>0$.

Answer (score 1):

I think natural logarithm is a good function for your purpose. It's increasing and have low-rate slope, lower than your diagram. Let $f(x)=a+b\ln x$, then $f(2x)<2f(x)$ concludes that $\displaystyle\ln\frac{2}{x}<\frac{a}{b}$. In other hand for $0.1<x<10$ gives us $$-1.6<\ln\frac{2}{x}<3$$ so we must set $\displaystyle3<\frac{a}{b}$ and we have $0<3b<a$.

For example set $a=4$ and $b=1$ which satisfy our condition, so $f(x)=4+\ln x$ has the condition $f(2x)<2f(x)$ with below diagram in $[0.1,10]$:

[image: $f(x)=4+\ln x$]

Below graph shows $f(2x)<2f(x)$ in $[0.1,10]$:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

$\log(x)$ comes to mind, but we also need to consider $f(2x)\lt2f(x)$. If we set $f(x)=\log(20x)$, then, since $x\gt0.1$,
$$
\begin{align}
f(2x)
&=\log(40x)\\
&=\log(2)+\log(20x)\\
&=\log(2)+f(x)\\
&\lt f(x)+f(x)\\
&=2f(x)
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Constant  $a$ in

$$ 1- e^{-x/a}$$

changes climb rate as desired.  ( Twice the function value more than function with double argument).

[image: 2 curves]